# Asymptotics of a double integral: $ \int_0^{\infty}du\int_0^{\infty}dv\, \frac{1}{(u+v)^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right)$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, asymptotics, multiple-integral

I want to calculate the asymptotic form as $x \to 0$ of the following integral.
\begin{alignat}{2}
I_2(x) &=&& \int_0^{\infty}du\int_0^{\infty}dv\, \frac{1}{(u+v)^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right) \\
&=&& \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \int_0^{\infty}du\int_0^{\infty}dv\, \exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right)
\end{alignat}
How can we solve?
This question is related with [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61498/a-four-dimensional-integral-in-peskin-schroeder).
Thanks.

Comment: As written, this double integral is *divergent*.

Comment: @Olivier: Yes. I want to calculate the asymptotic form as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Are you interested in an asymptotics of $\int_0^M du\int_0^{\infty}dv\, \frac{1}{(u+v)^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right)$ as $x \to 0^+$?

Comment: @Olivier: Yes I am.

Comment: Ok, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $M\ge1, x>0$. One may obtain, as $x \to 0^+$,

> $$
> \int_0^M\!\!\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\Large -\frac{x}{u+v}}}{(u+v)^2} \:du\:dv=-\log x-\gamma+1+\log M+\frac{x}{2M}-\frac{x^2}{12 M^2}+O(x^3).
> $$
>   where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

**Hint**. The above integrand is positive, one may then write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^M\!\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\Large -\frac{x}{u+v}}}{(u+v)^2} \:du\:dv&=\int_0^M\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\Large -\frac{x}{u+v}}}{(u+v)^2} \:du\right)dv
\\&=\int_0^M\left[\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{u+v}}}{x}\right]_0^\infty dv
\\&=\frac1x\int_0^M\left(1-e^{-\large\frac{x}{v}}\right) dv
\\&=\frac1x\int_{1/M}^\infty\left(1-e^{-\large xt}\right)\frac{dt}{t^2}
\\&=\frac1x \left(M-e^{-\frac{x}{M}} M+x\: \Gamma\left(0,x/M\right)\right)
\\&=-\log x-\gamma+1+\log M+\frac{x}{2M}-\frac{x^2}{12 M^2}+O(x^3)
\end{align}
$$ where we have used the [incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2)
$$
\Gamma(a,z):=\int_z^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt
$$ and its [asymptotics expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4#E15) ($a=0=-n$).

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{x}\left( M-e^{-\frac{x}{M}}M \right)=1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{M}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{x^2}{M^2}+\cdots$$
And from 8.4.15 of [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4#E15),
$$ \Gamma(0,\frac{x}{M})=-\gamma -\log \frac{x}{M} +\left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{k} \right)\frac{x}{M} $$
Right?

Comment: When I printed the web page, $(-z)^k$ wasn't correctly printed.
Then the correct expression is $\Gamma(0,\frac{x}{M})=-\gamma -\log \frac{x}{M} +\left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{k} \frac{(-x)^k}{M^k}\right)$.

Comment: @GotchaP Yes, this time it's Ok ;)

Comment: The correct result is $$-\log x-\gamma-1+\log M+\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{M}-\frac{x^2}{12 M^2}+O(x^3)$$

Comment: @GotchaP I don't understand your $\color{red}{-}1$. The first term in the expansion of $\frac{1}{x}\left( M-e^{-\frac{x}{M}}M \right)$ as $x \to 0$ is $1$, not $\color{red}{-}1$.

Comment: Sorry. The correct result is: $$-\log x-\gamma+1+\log M+\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{M}-\frac{x^2}{12 M^2}+O(x^3).$$

Comment: Please see the 9th line. I've looked at this line, not the 2nd line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: @GotchaP You are very welcome.

Comment: I've posted [a new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073025/deriving-gamma-n-z) about deriving [8.4.15](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4#E15).