# Asymptotics of a double integral

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, asymptotics, multiple-integral

I want to  calculate the asymptotic form as $x\to 0$ of the following integral.
\begin{alignat}{2}
I_2(x) = \int_0^{\infty}du\int_0^{\infty}dv\, \frac{1}{(u+v)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right)  
\end{alignat}

How can we solve?

This question is related with this post ([Asymptotics of a double integral: $ \int_0^{\infty}du\int_0^{\infty}dv\, \frac{1}{(u+v)^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064427/asymptotics-of-a-double-integral-int-0-inftydu-int-0-inftydv-frac1)), 
or the solutions in three-dimensional space for this post (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61498/a-four-dimensional-integral-in-peskin-schroeder#)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \frac{1}{(u+v)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right)\,dv=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{\sqrt{x}}\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{u+v}}\right)$$

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(u+v)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{u+v}\right)\,dv=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{x}}\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{u}}\right)$$

$$\int \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{u}}\right)\,du=(u+2 x)\, \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{u}}\right)+\frac{2 \sqrt{u} \sqrt{x}
  }{\sqrt{\pi }} e^{-\frac{x}{u}}$$
$$\int_0^M \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{u}}\right)\,du=(M+2 x) \,\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{M}}\right)+\frac{2 \sqrt{M} \sqrt{x}
   }{\sqrt{\pi }}e^{-\frac{x}{M}}-2 x$$ which does not converge if $M\to \infty$.
$$I_2(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{x}}\int_0^M \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{u}}\right)\,du=2 \sqrt{M} e^{-\frac{x}{M}}-2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{x}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } (M+2 x)
   }{\sqrt{x}}\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{M}}\right)\tag 1$$ Using series, we should end with $$I_2(x)=4 \sqrt{M}-2 \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{x}+\frac{4 x}{3 \sqrt{M}}-\frac{2 x^2}{15
   M\sqrt{M}}+O\left(x^3\right)$$

**Edit**

Concerning the derivatives of $I_2(x)$, using $(1)$, we should have 
$$\frac{d}{dx} I_2(x)=\frac{\sqrt{M} e^{-\frac{x}{M}}}{x}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left((M-2 x)
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{M}}\right)-M\right)}{2 x^{3/2}}$$

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} I_2(x)=-\frac{3 \sqrt{M} e^{-\frac{x}{M}}}{2 x^2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left((3 M-2 x)
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{M}}\right)+2 x\right)}{4 x^{5/2}}$$

Expanding as series around $x=0$, this would lead to 
$$\frac{d}{dx} I_2(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{M}}-\frac{4 x}{15
   M^{3/2}}+O\left(x^{2}\right)$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} I_2(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2 x^{3/2}}-\frac{4}{15 M^{3/2}}+\frac{4 x}{35
   M^{5/2}}+O\left(x^{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks you very much. I would like to ask, if the above results on the $x$ derivative, this is reasonable?

Comment: @Samurai. I am not sure I understand. Do you want the asymptotics of $\frac{d}{dx}I_2(x)$ ? Tell me if this is the case. I should look at it tomorrow morning (here it is almost 5:00pm French time). Cheers.

Comment: nice answer @ClaudeLeibovici (+1)

Comment: strange i get a leading term $M \sqrt{\pi/x}$.. i will come back later (first some sports..)

Comment: @tired. You are right : first, some sports ! Second : may be some mistakes on my side (I shall redo the work tomorrow morning - it is 8:00pm here). Third : I shall wait for your work. Cheers :-)

Comment: @tired. I may be wrong but I stil get the same results. I doble checked using numerical integration.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Thanks a lot. I mean whether this condition is reasonable for $\partial_x I_2= \partial_x [4\sqrt{M}-2\sqrt{\pi x}+\mathcal{O}(x)]  =- \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{x}}$, when $M \to \infty$.

Comment: @Samurai. Have a look  to my edit.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici. Thank you very much, your answer is very helpful to me

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici you are right i think, i messed things up... :( well done again!